# Continued fraction including cdots and dfrac

Tags: math-mode

Consider the following image of a snippet of text. I would like to know how this is reproduced, especially with the diagonal '\cdots' and \dfrac.

[image: Continued Fraction]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt to reproduce the screenshot you've posted. The code uses a top-aligned `array` environment. The `amsmath` package provides the `\dfrac` macro. Note that I've tried to assure the correct spacing around the `+` symbols, something that the screenshot does not do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\frac{u_0}{u_1}=\xi_0=a_0+
  \begin{array}[t]{ccc}
  \dfrac{1}{a_1+{}}\\
  \ddots\\
  & {}+{} & \dfrac{1}{a_{j-1}+\dfrac{1}{a_j}}.
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: So simple actually and intuitive... ddots!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \frac{u_0}{u_1} = \xi_0 = a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1 + \cfrac{1}{\dotsb + \cfrac{1}{a_{j-1} + \cfrac{1}{a_j}}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this (if you use this multiple times, create a command that expands to the whole `\vcenter{..}` expression)

```
\[
  \frac{u_0}{u_1} = \xi_0 = a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1 + \cfrac{1}{\vcenter{\hbox{$\ddots$}} + \cfrac{1}{a_{j-1} + \cfrac{1}{a_j}}}}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, note the difference in the dots.

Comment: I am specifically interested in how the 'diagonal dots' are done.

Comment: You have to use `\ddots` but since the dots sit quite high, it doesn't look good, I used `\vcenter{\hbox{$\ddots$}}` to lower it down (in fact, centering the symbol around the math axis).